# Why does my model $R^2$ drop when the intercept term is removed?

Tags: regression, python, least-squares, r-squared

I ran an Ordinary Least Squares model and found the constant/intercept is more significant than all the other features. When the intercept is included, the $R^2$ is 45%. When I remove the intercept, the $R^2$ drops to 29%.

The intercept also has the lowest p-value compared to all the other features.

Moreover, I used StandardScaler to scale the features used.

Why would the intercept be so significant?

Example code:

`model_2 = sm.OLS(df_reg_y.astype(float), sm.add_constant(X_scaled.astype(float))).fit()`

This area circled in purple is the scatter plot of the target variable vs the most significant feature. The histogram below it is the distribution of the target variable.

[image]

Edit: I realized that I forgot to scale the target variable. The issue was fixed after I scaled the features and target variable together.

Comment: Hard to tell without data, your data may be partially constant, hence why it has such a big effect.

Comment: @user2974951 So how would I intercept this finding? All the other features are relatively insignificant compared to the intercept. The most significant feature only accounts for 6% of R-squared.

Comment: Your data may not be linearly dependent, that is constant / non-changing. You should plot the results and add them here.

Comment: Did you scale the response variable too?

Comment: @VincentGuillemot Thank you! I made a silly mistake by not scaling the target variable. Now the y-intercept does not change R-squared. I'd accept you as the answer

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question was  rooted in a coding error that was identified and fixed by the OP (as stated in comments and the question edit).

Answer (score 1):

Noting this in an answer as it solved the problem and the community has voted to keep the question open:

The intercept is significant because the mean value of the response is detectably greater than zero. As you discovered, if you rescale the response variable by subtracting the mean, the intercept will be zero and no longer significant in subsequent analyses. And the $R^2$ will be identical for models with and without the intercept term.

Answer (score 0):

The intercept is there to account for the mean value of your dependent variable. By setting the intercept to 0, you are biasing your estimator, i.e. making the mean of the error different from 0.

The R squared is sensitive to this bias change. If you want a measure for the goodness of fit that only considers variance (is insensitive to bias) and behaves like R squared, you can go for explained variance.

In other words, R squared is a summary statistic, but it does not tell you whether it is your bias or your variance that is restricting the goodness of your fit.